# Is there a way to use an actual SQL Query (using Performance_schema from MySql) in SpringBoot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm new in Spring and SpringBoot in general.
I came here because i can't find a way to use Performance Schema in my queries to my local MysqlDB using Spring.

I tried using the @Query anotation but i found out that it uses JPQL.

My Query

```
    SELECT EVENT_ID, TRUNCATE(TIMER_WAIT / 1000000000000, 6) AS Duration, SQL_TEXT 
    FROM performance_schema.events_statements_history_long
    WHERE (TRUNCATE(TIMER_WAIT / 1000000000000, 6)) > 0.002;
```

(Please ignore this terrible query, i just want to show that i want to use performance_schema tables )
What i saw is that i should use JPQL for queries, but i don't see how i can do it if performance_schema is "hidden".

I'm trying to get information about queries in my DB, monitoring in general. That's why im using Performance Schema.

I would love to know how can i pass this query or if there is another way of getting this kind of information from my DB (not only this query, this is an example of what i would be doing).

Also, why is there so little information about Performance schema. Is it not good? Is there another tool that i can't find?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

There is no information about queries there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema
this structure is used by database itself to optimize queries (usually).

Answer (score 0):

- Old versions of MySQL did not have `PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA`.  What version are you using?
- `TRUNCATE()`??  Maybe you meant `FLOOR()` or `ROUND()`?
- See also

  ```
  EXPLAIN SELECT ...
  EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...
  the slowlog -- turn on and have `long_query_time = 1`.
  ```

Comment: My Query works fine from i.e MySql Workbench. It gives me the information that i need. Maybe my post wasn't clear. I want to use that query using Spring Boot and i can't find a way to get performance details (i.e execution time) from my MySql using "raw" SQL